testing nginx in github actions
I'm trying to test the deployment of a django app with github actions and I wanted to test if Nginx accepts request correctly on a certain url path with curl command.
the actions yaml file is as follows:
name: Test deployment

on:
  push:

jobs:
  automated_deployment:
    name: Deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Execute auto-deployment
        run: |
          bash auto-deployment.bash

  nginx_test:
    name: Set up server IP and check Nginx
    needs: automated_deployment
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Generate IP address and Check Nginx
        run: |
          # Generate the IP address
          EXTERNAL_IP=$(curl -s ifconfig.me)
          echo "External IP from script: $EXTERNAL_IP"  # Use the EXTERNAL_IP variable

          # Check Nginx with curl
          curl -I "http://$EXTERNAL_IP/conectdb/"
          exit_code=$?
          if [ $exit_code -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "Nginx is running."
          else
            echo "Failed to connect to Nginx. Exit code: $exit_code"
            exit $exit_code
          fi


In fact, the error generated in the run is
curl: (28) Failed to connect to 20.57.44.37 port 80 after 134130 ms: Connection timed out Error: Process completed with exit code 28. which means the script generates the correct ip adress but cannot connect to it on port 80.
I appreciate any advice about this subject because I'm not even sur that what I'm trying to do is allowed in the github actions container structure :)
I tried to integrate the curl command inside a bash script but it still give the same error.
